# Compatibility issue between dplyr versions in RStudio: Error with mutate function in newer version?

Tags: r, dplyr

In our team, we rely heavily on the dplyr package in our R scripts. Recently, we encountered a compatibility? issue related to different versions of RStudio and dplyr.

Some team members have the latest version of RStudio and dplyr (1.1.2), while others are using dplyr version 1.1.0. Interestingly, when team members with the newer version run the same code, they encounter a mutate error, while those with the older version do not face any issues.

We suspect that this error might be due to the package version difference, but we wanted to share our experience and seek suggestions from the community.

We did find a temporary solution by commenting out the code section that triggers the mutate error. This allows the code to run without any issues.

Here is the part of the code that gives mutate error :

```
         SY_Flag = case_when(
       SY_Dup2 == T & lag(SY_Dup2, default = F) == T &
         Location == 'Sales' & lag(Location == 'Sales') &
         SY_Del !=T & lag (SY_Del, default = T) != T
       ~ T
     )
```

Has anyone else experienced a similar compatibility problem between different versions of RStudio and dplyr? If so, how did you resolve it?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the 1.1.2 or 1.1.1 release notes that applies here. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/news/news.html.  One note, I think it would be better practice to use FALSE and TRUE instead of F and T, as those values can be overwritten, e.g. `F <- TRUE` will create chaos for your code.

Comment: It's also unnecessary to have a test like `TEST == T` when you can just use `TEST`, assuming it's a logical value already.

Comment: There is only one case, which makes me wonder why you are using `case_when`; presumably `mutate(SY_Flag = SY_Dup2 & lag(SY_Dup2, default = FALSE) & Location == 'Sales' & lag(Location == 'Sales') & !SY_Del & !lag(SY_Del, default = TRUE))` would do the same thing?

Comment: BTW, what is the mutate error? Unexpected result or do you get error text?

Comment: @JonSpring the error is : "Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `SY_Flag = case_when(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `TagRFId = "942 000004690323"`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the left-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error in `vec_c()`:
! Can't convert `..1` <logical> to <vctrs_unspecified>"  I bypassed it by Sy_Flag = FALSE

Comment: @JonSpring Yes, I agree on practising TRUE and FLASE, Its just that I have been given a repo with lots of code and the plan is to do tweaks in time. I did change thm in this case and didn't make a difference. I am reluctant to accept its the package issue since the mutate function is being used in other parts of the code with no error. But as we are using the same repo  and code and all other variables are the same except the package and RStudio versions, it made me investigate the possibility.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you have not specified what the value should be when the tests are not met. In the past, people would often end `case_when()` calls with a line like `TRUE ~ NA_logical_)` so any cases where tests aren't met outputs a logical-type NA. Now there's `.default`. You haven't specified what should happen then. I think the error might be related to the underlying `vctrs` package not knowing what type to output when `TagRFId = "942 000004690323"` -- perhaps that's a group where all the outputs fail the test, so the output is NA, but it doesn't know which type of NA to give.

Comment: @JonSpring hmm, so do u think the issue is with vctrs package? However, I find it puzzling that some team members can run the code without encountering any errors. The only difference seems to be that they have newer versions of R and the related packages. To test this theory, I attempted to unload the newer package and install an older version of plyr using different methods like renv and <Rtools>. Unfortunately, I haven't had any success due to the constraints imposed by our organisational policy, which prevents updating the Rtools path in the system environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253927/discussion-between-hank-and-jon-spring).